# How to set HTML5 video aspect ratio in fancybox gallery?

Tags: css, fancybox

I am using the latest version of [fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/ui). I'm trying to create a gallery of vertical HTML5 videos. But fancybox automatically calculates aspect ratio and in the end I get the following:
[image]

How to make a full-screen video?

Answer (score 0):

To make a video display in full-screen mode with Fancybox, you can use the iframe option and set the aspectRatio to "true". This will force the video to fill the entire screen. Here's an example code snippet:

```js
  $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    iframe: {
      css: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      },
      attr: {
        allowfullscreen: true,
      },
      aspectRatio: true,
    },
    thumbs: false, // Disable thumbnails if you don't need them
    buttons: [
      "zoom",
      "fullScreen",
      "close",
    ],
  });
```

```html
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="video-url" href="javascript:;">
  <img src="thumbnail-url" alt="Video Thumbnail">
</a>
```

In this example, you have an anchor tag () that contains an image thumbnail of the video. The data-fancybox attribute is used to initialize the Fancybox gallery. Set the data-type attribute to "iframe" and provide the URL of the video in the data-src attribute.

Inside the JavaScript code, the Fancybox options are configured. The iframe object is used to define the settings for the video iframe. By setting aspectRatio to true, the video will automatically adjust its dimensions to fill the available space and appear in full-screen mode.

Additionally, the Fancybox configuration includes options for buttons, such as zoom, full screen, and close buttons. Adjust these options as per your requirements.

Make sure you have included the Fancybox library and its dependencies in your project for this code to work properly.